# how to visualize aligment tree .dnd done with t coffee

Tags: r, tree, bioinformatics

I've tried 2 explained packages in R, but the output is the same: Null device 1

I'm working in the same directory my resul.dnd is

```
install.packages("ape")
library(ape)
MyTree <- read.tree("result.dnd")
png("result.png")
plot(MyTree)
dev.off()

install.packages("phytools")
library(phytools)
MyTree <- read.newick("result.dnd")
png("results.png")
plot(MyTree)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Is the `results.png` file being created on disk? Have you tried to open it? How many bytes does it have? These commands won't show anything on screen; they will just write to the file on disk. Are you running these commands in an interactive session or are you running them from a scropt?

Comment: it doesn't create any file on my directory (as far as I know). I'm running these commands on a Rmarkdown. rmd file.

Comment: If you are running in an RMarkdown file, you normally don't use `png("results.png")` and `dev.off()`. That interferes with Rmarkdown's ability to capture the image assuming you want the image to appear in the resulting document. Try removing those commands.